# environment variables for daemons

Tags: environment-variables, daemon

I have processes started as daemons or from cron.

They can run under users account without a shell.

1. how can I set system wide environment variables ?
   I mean the environment sourced to all processes, prior to user logins.
2. have I to account for special considerations, tricks, side effects ? 
   specifically about the variable LD_PRELOAD

Comment: On what distribution?

Comment: unfortunately our farm has centos debian and ubuntu servers, from 2.4 to 3.x kernels (running legacy software and providers don't help to update, their policy is  'the server is in LAN and it is running ...')

Answer (score 3):

There is no universal method to set system-wide environment variables.

With systemd, [add `Environment=` statements to the service configuration](https://serverfault.com/questions/413397/how-to-set-environment-variable-in-systemd-service).

With Upstart, [add `env` statements to the job configuration](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#environment-variables).

With SysVinit, add `export` statements to the service startup script.

For cron jobs, add `VAR=VALUE` lines to the crontab.

`LD_PRELOAD` changes the behavior of a program in ways that were not intended by the author of the program, so you should set it only for the programs that really need it. Even if there was a way to set a system-wide environment variable, `LD_PRELOAD` should not be set so broadly.

Comment: disregarding LD_PRELOAD, for common variables : can I set them using a fake demon script in /etc/init.d ?

Comment: does yor cron example set the  variable system wide or only for the same line job ?

Comment: @Massimo A variable that is set in a crontab is set for the jobs in that crontab. Cron has no way to influence the environment of things other than cron jobs. I don't know what you mean by “fake demon script”.

Comment: I found in the past daemons that don't launch forever living processes, but just make some actions and "quit" ( no process left running ). So they have only a "start" action and the "stop" is really a NOP.

Comment: what about, as universal solution, a script in /etc/profile.d/ ?

Comment: @Massimo That sets variables for login sessions but not for cron jobs or system services.

Comment: kernel cmdline : http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bootparam.7.html : Anything of the form 'foo=bar' that is not accepted as a setup function as described above is then interpreted as an environment variable to be set ... does it work ?

Comment: this PROVA=123 doesn't work : cat /proc/cmdline :
 root=LABEL=/ console=tty1 console=ttyS0 selinux=0 nousb transparent_hugepage=never ipv6.disable=1 PROVA=123